# Javascript need variable that can represent any number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, numbers

I'm a javascript novice so this may be a dumb question. I'm trying to generate a script that takes the phrase "(x items)" and changes it to "(x)", where x can represent any number.

Here's what I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       function changeText(){
           $(".CartLink:contains('2 items')").html('<a href="/cart.php">Cart <span>(2)</span></a>');
            }
       changeText();
       $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
       changeText();
       });
    });
</script>
```

The above script is able to replace the phrase "(2 items)" with "(2)" but I need to modify the script so that 2 can be any number. Thank you.

This is the HTML that .CartLink element contains:

```
<li style="display:" class="CartLink"><a href="/cart.php">Cart <span>%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%</span></a></li>
```

Comment: @lordvlad: that is not what this question is about.

Comment: What html does the `.CartLink` element contain before you alter it?

Comment: my bad. i mixed up something...

Comment: @jason-p This is the HTML that .CartLink element contains: <li style="display:" class="CartLink"><a href="/cart.php">Cart <span>%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%</span></a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this should be a server-side task. But if you have a limitation requiring you to do this client-side...

You don't need to replace all of the html. You can simply modify the text of the `span`:

```
$('.CartLink span').text(function(_, val) {
    return val.replace(' items', '');
});
```

Comment: This solution is working best so far. The only issue is that the page has to refresh for the script to work once a new item is added to the cart. Is there a solution for that you know of?

Comment: Are you executing this snippet every time an item is added to the cart?

Comment: I'm adding the snippet to the footer so I think it only executes when the page refreshes. When an item gets added to the cart there's a pop-up but no page refresh. Would it help if I added the script to the pop-up code?

Comment: Put this snippet in a function, then call that function in the footer, and when an item is added to the cart. I assume it's using ajax, so you should be able to call it from the success or done callback.

Comment: Right now after adding to the cart you click this link: ``<a href="#" onclick="$('.modalClose').trigger('click');">Continue Shopping</a>``. Can I add something here to trigger the snippet or refresh the page after the modal closes?

Comment: You could call the function then, sure. It would probably be ideal to call it from the ajax callback though. Maybe where the modal is triggered?

Comment: Here's the code that triggers the modal: ``<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary AddCartButton" value="Add to Cart" />`` Could you tell me what I would need to add here to call the snippet? (I'm not a programmer so I don't know how to create an ajax callback, sorry)

Comment: Either the page is actually refreshing, or there's a javascript event handler that listens for the `submit` event and does an ajax call instead.

Comment: nevermind actually, i think i figured it out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your can use split to seperate the count and text.

http://jsfiddle.net/B2meD/

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".CartLink").html('<a href="/cart.php">Cart <span>'+$(".CartLink").text().split(" ")[0]+'</span></a>');
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about. And `String.split(" ").pop()` is more efficient than selecting, plus you would want to select the LAST item in the array. So [1] would be the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript as a string replace method. So you can simply remove the items part.

```
var foo = ('2 items');
var newFoo = foo.replace("items", "");
```

Then newFoo would become ('2')

Comment: Actually, i just tested this. alert(newFoo); just gave me 2. `var foo = ("'2 items'")'; alerts '2 '. But who cares lol

Comment: Actually, there's a space behind 2 no matter what you say. You would have to do `foo.replace(" items", "");`. Either way, not as good as a `.split()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the "2" variable from?

```
var items = 2;
items ++; //items = 3;
$('.Cart').html("Items in cart:" + items.toString() + ". Foo");
```

See how I added the "+" to add up the strings?

**I must add, this is just bad js.**

For making your items variable:

```
var str = "(Items 2)";
var numberStr = "(" + str.split(" ").pop(); //makes "(2)" or use .replace or whatever works.
```

Keep in mind that making a variable from a string will result in another string. If you want to manipulate your new items var as a number, you have to get an integer like so,

```
var numberStr = "(3)";
var int = parseFloat(numberStr.replace(/["'()]/g,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

S('.CartLink').text($('.CartLink').text().split(' ')[0])

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your changeText function with this it should work as you want:

```
function changeText() {
    var itemCountSpan = $(".CartLink a span")
    if (/(\d+) items/.test(itemCountSpan.text())) {
        itemCountSpan.text(RegExp.$1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple RegEx version.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function changeText(){
        $(".CartLink").each(function() {
            var newhtml = $(this).html().replace(/\((\d+) items\)/, "($1)");
            $(this).html(newhtml);
        });
    }
    changeText();
});
```

It looks at every element with the CartLink class for the string `(x items)` where x is one or more digits and removes the word "items". `$1` is a property that gets set when the `(\d+)` parenthesised match is made, allowing us to use the number we want in our replacement string.